# Scrapy: extracting data using response.text

Tags: python

I am trying to get comments from this [site](https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-zach-olesinski-toronto-on-ca). How can I do that?

Is this the only method?

```
response = response.text.replace("\\","").replace("u0022","")
```

But it's just text, I can’t access by key `response['sample_rating_comment']`

```
>>> response = response.text.replace("\\","").replace("u0022","")
>>> response['sample_rating_comment']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Comment: do you know how to use `response.xpath(...)` or `response.css(...)` to search on page?

Comment: BTW: this page use JavaScript to add some elements but Scrapy can't run JavaScript and whould need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to run JavaScript. ie. [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) or [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#usage)

Comment: I don't see `sample_rating_comment` on this page or subpage.

Comment: I found `sample_rating_comment` in JavaScript code but in HTML the same text is in `<p class="reviewBody">` If you need text from JavaScript code then you could get `<script>` (using `response.xpath` or `response.css`) and use string operation to cut off needed `JSON.parse(...)` and use module `json` to convert it to python dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really use `scrapy` then you should use `response.xpath()` or `response.css()` to find all `<script>` and check which one has expected `sample_rating_comment`

And then you can get this script as text and use `find()` and slicing `[start:end]` to cut off text in `JSON.parse(...)` and use `json.loads()` to convert to python dictionary.

---

You didn't put `scrapy` code which get this page so I create example with `requests`, `beautifulsoup`

BTW: you have to convert `\u0022` to `"` (not remove it) to create correct JSON string for `json.loads()`. Or better use

```
text = text.encode().decode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

to convert all `\uXXXX` to correct chars

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
}

url = 'https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-zach-olesinski-toronto-on-ca'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#print(r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
#print('len:', len(all_scripts))

for script in all_scripts:
    if 'window.DATA.doctorDetailProps = JSON.parse("' in script.text:
        text = script.text 
       
        start = text.find('window.DATA.doctorDetailProps = JSON.parse("') + len('window.DATA.doctorDetailProps = JSON.parse("')
        end   = text.find('")', start)
        #print(text[start:end])

        text = text[start:end]
        #text = text.replace(r'\u0022', '"')
        text = text.encode().decode('raw_unicode_escape')
        data = json.loads(text)
        
        #print(json.dumps(data['doctor'], indent=2))
        #print(data['doctor'].keys())
        
        print('\n--- full_name ---\n')
        print(data['doctor']['full_name'])
        
        print('\n--- sample_rating_comment ---\n')
        print(data['doctor']['sample_rating_comment'])
        
        print('\n--- comments ---\n')
        for result in data['ratingsPage']['results']:
            print(result['comment'])#.encode().decode('raw_unicode_escape')) # convert `\uXXXX'
            print('\n---\n')
```

Result:

```
--- full_name ---

Zach Olesinski

--- sample_rating_comment ---

Zach’s acupuncture is a magical experience. He carefully selected a few numbers of points and I noticed my elevated heart rate (from stress) slowed down. I felt very relaxed by the end of the session. He helped me with my digestive issues, sleep and lower back pain.

--- comments ---

Zach’s acupuncture is a magical experience. He carefully selected a few numbers of points and I noticed my elevated heart rate (from stress) slowed down. I felt very relaxed by the end of the session. He helped me with my digestive issues, sleep and lower back pain.

---

Zach is a true healer. I saw him regularly in Vancouver and he helped me tremendously with my gut issues. He actually listens to you and the whole experience is very comfortable and relaxing. I am so sad he moved to Toronto, but I'm happy for all of the new clients who will get the chance to work with him.

---

Zacks treatments are incredible. I went to see him to help relax my nervous system and help manage my stress levels. The treatments really helped and aided in my digestion as well. Zach has a very calming energy and unique talent for acupuncture, I highly recommend. 

---

Zach was recommended through one of my best friends, and I'm so glad I went. I saw him for neck / shoulder pain plus sometimes thore throat problem (I'm a voice actor, so it's very important to take care of my throat...). The effect is immediate, I felt 100% better each time. Also he calmed down my hyper active side, I felt deeply relaxed like after a good meditation, and was easy to focus after each session.
He is very knowledgeable and takes time to understand what you need. I would really recommend his services!!

---

I used to see Chinese accpuncturelist but it wasn't as effective to my body. After I got Zach's acupuncture treatment couple of times,I felt  my body getting better little by little. He is really gentle and informative! I highly recommend his acupuncture treatment!
ザックの鍼を受けるようになって体が少しずついい方向へ変化していくのがわかりました。日本式の鍼は全く痛みを感じないし、彼はとても親切で丁寧に対応してくれるので安心して任せられます。日本式の鍼を探している方がいらっしゃったら是非、ザックをお勧めします！

---
```